# Axios.get is returning html text file in builded react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, axios

I use react for front end and node js and express for the backend API.

I want to do a axios.get request to /api/authcheck I have set the "proxy": "http://161.97.108.206:4174" in package.json to the API's URL. It should be up so you would be able to access it, and if you do it will return either true or false, but in my react app it returns a html text file. Also worth noting is that my react app is built for production. My response is following:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,200,1,0"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><title>Portal</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.8d9b3796.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.2702701b.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

and this is from the built react app. The result I want from the API is either true or false, while I get a html text file for the moment.

I have tried to remove the `"proxy": "api url"` from package.json and put it in the axios request like this:

```
axios.get('http://161.97.108.206:4174/api/authcheck', { withCredentials: true }).then((res:AxiosResponse):void |any => {
   setLoggedIn(res.data)
   console.log(res.data)
 }).catch((err:AxiosError) => {
   console.log(err)
 })
```

but then I'm not able to access my cookies. In the API middleware I get the cookies by typing `req.cookies['access_token']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (Cors) middleware in javascript file -

```
const cors = require('cors)

app.use(cors({credentials:true}));
```

use res.status in GET request -

```
axios.get('http://161.97.108.206:4174/api/authcheck', { withCredentials: 
   true })
  .then((res: AxiosResponse) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      setLoggedIn(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    } else {
      console.log("Error: ", res.status);
    }
  })
  .catch((err: AxiosError) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Hello i get this error "Cannot find name 'credentials'. Did you mean 'Credential'?" when i try to add "app.use(cors( credentials : true));"

Comment: Try this one ->                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                 
const cors = require('cors)
                                                                                                                     app.use(cors());

Comment: I get this error then inside chrome console 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://161.97.108.206:4174/api/authcheck' from origin 'http://161.97.108.206:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Solved it app.use({credentials : true}); fixed it